# Cannot modify a column which maps to a non key preserved table in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

[image]I am rewriting an old piece of code. I am getting following error when I've added following inside select a.* block

```
FROM USB.DFP_DATA A, BAS2_DFP_OBLIGOR_FACTS C
                    where a.as_of_date = v_date and a.DFPDEAL_TAX_ID_NBR=c.DFPDEAL_TAX_ID_NBR(+) and a.as_of_Date = c.as_of_date(+)
```

Could you please let me know how this error can be resolved? Thanks in advance for kind help!

```
--new code. user will enter INSTTABLE  and date and it should run and update fields.

IF INSTTABLE = 5 THEN
    V_BASEL_MIN :=0.08;
    V_BAS_RWA_RATE:=BAS_RWA_ADJ_RATE(V_DATE); 

    UPDATE ( SELECT A.*,
                BAS2_RWA_CALC(BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL(CUR_BOOK_BAL,0), NVL(BAS_CAP_FACTOR_K,0), V_BASEL_MIN, V_BAS_RWA_RATE) AS V_BAS_EB_RWA,
                BAS2_RWA_CALC(BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL(CUR_BOOK_BAL,0), NVL(BAS_ICAAP_FACTOR_K,0), V_BASEL_MIN, V_BAS_RWA_RATE) AS V_BAS_ICAAP_EB_RWA,
                BAS2_RWA_CALC(BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL(AVG_BOOK_BAL,0), NVL(BAS_CAP_FACTOR_K,0), V_BASEL_MIN, V_BAS_RWA_RATE) AS V_BAS_AB_RWA,
                BAS2_RWA_CALC(BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL(BAS_UNUSED_COMMT,0), NVL(BAS_CAP_FACTOR_K_COMMT,0), V_BASEL_MIN, V_BAS_RWA_RATE) AS V_BAS_EB_RWA_COMMT,
                BAS2_RWA_CALC(BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL(BAS_UNUSED_COMMT,0), NVL(BAS_ICAAP_FACTOR_K_COMMT,0), V_BASEL_MIN, V_BAS_RWA_RATE) AS V_BAS_ICAAP_EB_RWA_COMMT,
                BAS2_RWA_CALC(BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL(BAS_UNUSED_COMMT,0), NVL(BAS_CAP_FACTOR_K_COMMT,0), V_BASEL_MIN, V_BAS_RWA_RATE) AS V_BAS_AB_RWA_COMMT,
                BAS2_RWA_CALC(BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD,NVL(BAS_PART_UNUSED_COMMT,0), NVL(BAS_CAP_FACTOR_K_COMMT,0), V_BASEL_MIN, V_BAS_RWA_RATE) AS V_BAS_PART_EB_RWA_COMMT,
                BAS2_RWA_CALC(BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD,NVL(BAS_PART_UNUSED_COMMT,0), NVL(BAS_ICAAP_FACTOR_K_COMMT,0), V_BASEL_MIN, V_BAS_RWA_RATE) AS V_BAS_ICAAP_EB_RWA_PART,
                BAS2_RWA_CALC(BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD,NVL(BAS_PART_UNUSED_COMMT,0), NVL(BAS_CAP_FACTOR_K_COMMT,0), V_BASEL_MIN, V_BAS_RWA_RATE) AS V_BAS_PART_AB_RWA_COMMT
                FROM USB.DFP_DATA A, BAS2_DFP_OBLIGOR_FACTS C
                    where a.as_of_date = v_date and a.DFPDEAL_TAX_ID_NBR=c.DFPDEAL_TAX_ID_NBR(+) and a.as_of_Date = c.as_of_date(+))
    SET
                BAS_EB_RWA = V_BAS_EB_RWA,
                BAS_ICAAP_EB_RWA = V_BAS_ICAAP_EB_RWA,
                BAS_AB_RWA = V_BAS_AB_RWA,
                BAS_EB_RWA_COMMT = V_BAS_EB_RWA_COMMT,
                BAS_ICAAP_EB_RWA_COMMT = V_BAS_ICAAP_EB_RWA_COMMT,
                BAS_AB_RWA_COMMT = V_BAS_AB_RWA_COMMT,
                BAS_PART_EB_RWA_COMMT = V_BAS_PART_EB_RWA_COMMT,
                BAS_ICAAP_EB_RWA_PART = V_BAS_ICAAP_EB_RWA_PART,
                BAS_PART_AB_RWA_COMMT = V_BAS_PART_AB_RWA_COMMT,
                BAS_EB_EXPECTED_LOSS = BAS2_EL_CALC(CUR_BOOK_BAL,bas_unused_commt,BAS_PD,BAS_LGD,BAS_LEQ,BAS_EAD,BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD),
                BAS_AB_EXPECTED_LOSS = BAS2_EL_CALC(AVG_BOOK_BAL,bas_unused_commt,BAS_PD,BAS_LGD,BAS_LEQ,BAS_EAD,BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD),
                BAS_EB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = round(BAS2_MGRL_CAPITAL(v_date, v_BAS_EB_RWA,v_BAS_EB_RWA_COMMT),2),
                BAS_AB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = round(BAS2_MGRL_CAPITAL(v_date, v_BAS_AB_RWA,v_BAS_AB_RWA_COMMT),2),
                BAS_PART_EB_EXPECTED_LOSS= BAS2_EL_CALC(0,bas_part_unused_commt,BAS_PD,BAS_LGD,BAS_LEQ,BAS_EAD,BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD), 
                BAS_PART_AB_EXPECTED_LOSS= BAS2_EL_CALC(0,bas_part_unused_commt,BAS_PD,BAS_LGD,BAS_LEQ,BAS_EAD,BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD), 
                BAS_PART_EB_TOTAL_CAPITAL= round(BAS2_MGRL_CAPITAL(v_date, 0,nvl(v_BAS_PART_EB_RWA_COMMT,0)),2), 
                BAS_PART_AB_TOTAL_CAPITAL= round(BAS2_MGRL_CAPITAL(v_date, 0,nvl(v_BAS_PART_AB_RWA_COMMT,0)),2)
        WHERE
            (AS_OF_DATE = V_DATE);
END IF;
```

Expected-- It should run and update fields mentioned in SET block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will likely end up rewriting this with more modern `MERGE` syntax or doing the update in a different manner.

Your code is using an inline view as an updatable view, and there are some restrictions as to when you can update a view.

[Oracle docs on views, (search for "Notes on updatable views")](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8004.htm)

[A Look at Oracle Updatable Views](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-view/oracle-updatable-view/)

Comment: Thanks. I thought of same. I have a question though. All the columns and calculations are being performed which belongs to table DFP_DATA ( alias A) but I want to make sure update happen only when ```where a.as_of_date = v_date and a.DFPDEAL_TAX_ID_NBR=c.DFPDEAL_TAX_ID_NBR(+) and a.as_of_Date = c.as_of_date(+)``` condition matches

Comment: Could you please suggest how to put this in merge skeleton. Also, is it useful to use merge in this condition.

Comment: Is it correct to say that `BAS2_DFP_OBLIGOR_FACTS` was not in the original code? As it stands, I'm not sure what it would do if it were to work--the condition is an outer join, so the last two parts of your WHERE clause wouldn't exclude any records anyway. An outer join might not be the way to go with that table--perhaps something like an IN or EXISTS would work.